# Definir estilo no evento :hover de um elemento de forma inline em HTML?

Tags: html, css

É possível definir estilo(`CSS`) de um elemento `HTML` de forma `inline` no evento `:hover`?

Como definir estilo(`CSS`) de um elemento `HTML` de forma `inline` no evento `:hover`?

Comment: Resposta curta: **NÃO**. Uma forma de "simular" o efeito de `:hover` seria com Javascript (`onmouseover` e `onmouseout`). Respostas no StackOverflow: [link-um](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1033166/4056678) e [link-dois](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26376620/4056678).

Comment: @renan não quer fazer um "bem-bolado" das duas e postar como resposta? (com os devidos créditos, claro). Acho uma pergunta extremamente boa, seria bom uma resposta que, além do "não", mostrasse alternativas.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente não, por ser um pseudo-selector ele funciona apenas em folhas de estilo externas ou dentro do  da página em questão.